# Extracting countably many subnets from a net

Tags: general-topology, nets

Let $\{f_{\alpha,k}\}_{\alpha\in \mathcal A,k\in \mathbb N}\subseteq \mathbb R$, were $\mathcal A $ is a directed set. Suppose I know that for each $k$, and $\varepsilon >0$, there is $\bar \alpha  $ such that

$$|f_{\alpha,k}|<\varepsilon, $$
for all $\alpha \geq \bar \alpha$.

Can I find a monotone final function $h:\Lambda\to \mathcal A$, with $\Lambda$ a directed set, such that   for each $\varepsilon >0$ there is a $\bar \lambda$ such that

$$|f_{h(\lambda),k}|<\varepsilon, $$
for every $k\in \mathbb N$ and $\lambda 
\geq \bar\lambda$?